# Talend connector to Facebook Insight

Tags: talend, facebook-insights

We are setting up a data flow from Facebook Insight API to a big data platform. We are planning to use Talend. Is there a Talend connector that's fully functional and up-to-date?
I could only find out-of-date components.

The challenge we have is that Facebook authentication mandates a user interaction and we need to automate that.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment there are no fully functional and up-to-date Facebook components for Talend. You have to use the httprequest component.

For a nonexpireing token follow this instructions:
If you use the marketing API from Facebook you can add a `SystemUser` to the APP ; this will get a non-expiring access token for Facebook Insights.